# Share data between views (ViewPart) Equinox

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

got a little question here to Eclipse Plugins.

I have a java class which contains some data, e.g. a linkedlist and some other stuff.
I need this data in 2 views. In one view I want to display some of them, and the other view should show a list with the data. (this is my special case, but I ask the question generally).

So, how can I use this one class in both views? In "normal" java I'd would give a reference when I create the views, but as far as I know this is not possible in  eclipse plugins.

My solution is, that the data-class is a singleton. But I don't like this solution, I think this only works in my case.

Hope you got the point :) Do anyone of you know a better solution?

(i'm new in eclipse plugins, there aren't good books or tutorials, aren't there?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question in your post... try this site out for basic tutorials about Eclipse plug-ins and RCP applications.

[www.vogella.com/eclipse.html](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html)

This answer should help with the first question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

In SWT, all views just show a presentation of the underlying business objects. So when you implement the list and the tree, they just need to have the identical object as input (e.g. when calling `treeViewer.setInput(theSharedDataObject)`).

Your data class doesn't need to be a singleton for that, you just have to point to the *same instance* of the data.

Comment: okay, but where do I have to create the data object so that both views can access it?

Comment: Wherever you like, of course. I mean, both of those viewparts as well as the data are in the same plugin, so you refer to the data by importing the class as you always do in Java. Eclipse doesn't change anything compared to standalone Java applications. The boundaries between plugins are quite similar to the boundary between a Java application and a JAR used in that application. You can call from the code of one into the code of the other and of course you can pass any object where the type is known at the other side.